# (Xamarin MasterPageDetail ListView SelectedItem with MVVM) How to load menu page properly on click?

Tags: listview, mvvm, xamarin.forms, master-detail, selecteditem

I am not sure how to properly bind a selected menu item from a listview to its associated load page event in the view model.

The way I have it right now it works. **BUT, the problem is** that a menu page stays selected(still highlighted orange when sliding menu from left) and if clicked again the side menu does not disappear and nothing happens, until selecting a different page. ( IPropertyChanged does not trigger if clicking same item...or does it trigger anyways and checks if there is a change and sets it or not?)

How to fix this please in the correct MVVM way?

[image]
Notice in the photo last selection stays selected, and clicking again nothing happens when it should reload the page. Only clicking another page works.

The MasterDetailPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
                  x:Class="MyApp.Views.MyMainPage"
                  Title="My Main Page">


    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title="Menu">
            <ContentPage.Content>

                <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="130" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid>
                        <Image Source="menu_background.png" 
                       Aspect="AspectFill" />

                        <StackLayout Padding="0,20,0,0" 
                             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                             VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

                            <Image Source="ac_logo.png" 
                           Aspect="AspectFit" 
                           WidthRequest="60" 
                           HeightRequest="60" />

                            <Label Text="myAC" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large" />

                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" 
                         Spacing="15">

                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MenuList}"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding MenuSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          RowHeight="45"
                          SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                          BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8">

                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <!-- Main design for our menu items -->
                                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                 Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                 Padding="20,10,0,10"
                                                 Spacing="20">

                                                <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}"
                                                WidthRequest="30"
                                                HeightRequest="30"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center" />

                                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                                FontSize="Medium"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                TextColor="Black"/>
                                            </StackLayout>

                                            <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Gray"/>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                        </ListView>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>

            </ContentPage.Content>

        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>


    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:StudentHomePage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>


</MasterDetailPage>
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class MyMainPageVM : BaseVM
    {
        public ObservableCollection<MenuPageItem> MenuList { get; set; }

        private MenuPageItem _menuSelectedItem = null;
        public MenuPageItem MenuSelectedItem
        {
            get
            {
                return _menuSelectedItem;
            }

            set
            {
               //if (_menuSelectedItem != value) 
               // {
                    _menuSelectedItem = value;
                    // navigate
                    (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(_menuSelectedItem.TargetType));
                    (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).IsPresented = false;
                //}
            }
        }
        public MyMainPageVM()
        {
            MenuList = new ObservableCollection<MenuPageItem>();
            populateMenuList();


        }

        private void populateMenuList()
        {
            MenuList.Add(new MenuPageItem() { Title = "Home", IconSource = "home.png", TargetType = typeof(MyHomePage) });
            MenuList.Add(new MenuPageItem() { Title = "Setting", IconSource = "setting.png", TargetType = typeof(Page2) });
            MenuList.Add(new MenuPageItem() { Title = "Help", IconSource = "help.png", TargetType = typeof(Page3) });
        }

    }
```

My Base View Model Class:

```
public class BaseVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And finally the MasterPageDetail page CS:

```
public partial class MyMainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        private MyMainPageVM myMainPageVM;
        public MyMainPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            myMainPageVM = new MyMainPageVM();
            this.BindingContext = myMainPageVM       

        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `ListView.SelectedItem = null` to remove the hightLight state of the selected item when navigating to a new page.

To accsess the `ListView`, first, give the `ListView` a name in your `MasterDetailPage.xaml`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MenuList}"
                          electedItem="{Binding MenuSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          RowHeight="45"
                          SeparatorVisibility="Default"
                          BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8"

                          x:Name="masterListView">
```

In the code behind, create a `public static ListView masterList` and set the `masterList = masterListView`:

```
public partial class MyMainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    private MyMainPageVM myMainPageVM;


    public static ListView masterList;

    public MyMainPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myMainPageVM = new MyMainPageVM();
        //bindingContext = myMainPageVM;
        BindingContext = myMainPageVM;

        //Set the masterList
        masterList = masterListView;
    }
}
```

Then, you can access the listView in other class, `Set the SelectedItem=null` after navigate:

```
private MenuPageItem _menuSelectedItem = null;
public MenuPageItem MenuSelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return _menuSelectedItem;
    }

    set
    {           
        _menuSelectedItem = value;

        (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(_menuSelectedItem.TargetType));

        //Set the SelectedItem=null
        MyMainPage.masterList.SelectedItem = null;

        (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).IsPresented = false;

    }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hua its working. Its a good solution, thanks so much for it. But is it fuly MVVM compliant or a bit of a hack? Because the view model should know nothing about the view as I understand, but here we are reaching out into the viewlist specifically from the viewmodel to set the selected item to null.

Comment: Hua Would using a tap gesture with a bindable command be more MVVM compliant and considered a better solution? I haven't tried that yet but I got an idea on a forum. What do you think? Also is Xamarin a bit limiting when wanting to fully obey MVVM?

Comment: @EmilRR1 You can check the [sample in the  document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page), it's a mvvm project. I just tried to access the listView by following your logic.